# Javascript Validation(not focusable)

Tags: javascript

I am using HTML5 to validate my code but due to Javascript it is not submiting. It is showing the error
**Invalid form control with name="..." is not focusable**
for the feilds which are not selected. Since I have use Javascript for dynamic switching.
Heres the code

```
function prodType(value) {
  document
    .querySelectorAll(".fieldbox")
    .forEach((node) => (node.style.display = "none"));
    $("input").prop('required',true);
   
  document.getElementById(map[value]).style.display = "block";
 
}
```

I have tried the few solutions which were discussed before but it is not working.

```
function prodType(value) {
  document
    .querySelectorAll(".fieldbox")
    .forEach((node) => (node.style.display = "none"));
    $("input").prop('required',true);
   
  document.getElementById(map[value]).style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById('id here').removeAttribute = "required";
 
}
```

id here for the id for the for which it is showing error